# Creating Facebook Environment with Drupal

Tags: facebook, web, drupal-7

I have installed Drupal 7 with Acquia Drupal.

I would like to re-create the Facebook environment especially:

i) user initiated mapping/creation of friend networks.
ii) user wall for posting comments, pictures and have friends reply.
iii) user profile creation.

From the little research I have done, I see that most of the modules available for Drupal Allow Facebook integration on a Drupal site (e.g. Like, post comment on walls from Drupal site...etc) and are NOT modules which allow the creation of a Facebookesq environment. I am hoping that I am wrong.

Questions

1) Can you please let me know which modules would allow the creation of a Facebookesq environment?

2) Slighty different topic - what is the most simple way to modify the underlying HTML/CSS files created by Drupal?

3) where is the "node" file stored?

I want to thank you in advance for your time and effort in responding to my questions.

Comment: You are not wrong about the modules, drupal is a CMS not a facebook clone

Answer (score 1):

There is a series of modules in Drupal for working with Facebook Apps or creating Facebook type features. check [Drupal Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Drupal Commons, but it is for Drupal 6

Answer (score 0):

Try [The Ultimate Community Site Guide](http://book.drupalfun.com), it is a book I wrote about building a community site with Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you should check organic group and be prepared to write some code/modules.
2 and 3) I'm not sure what you are asking. If you can be a little more specific i may assist you